# Kubernetes is affecting cpu usage of pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cpu-usage

in my environment one kubernetes pod, let's call it P1, is connected outside the cluster via a message oriented middleware (MOM). The latter is publicly exposed through the following Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-mom-svc
spec:
  externalIPs:
    - aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
  selector:
    app: my-mom
  ports:
    - port: pppp
      name: my-port-name
```

Clients are outside the k8s cluster and connect to the MOM thanks to this service. P1 processes messages coming from the MOM and sent by the clients. My goal is to maximize the CPU used by P1.

I defined a limitrange so that P1 can use all the available CPUs on a worker node.
However, in my test environment it does not use all of them and indeed, the more pods like P1 I create the less CPU each of them uses (notice that there is only one pod like P1 for a single worker node).

I tried to define a resourcequota with a huge max cpu number, but the result does not change.

In desperation i entered into the pod and executed the command 'stress --cpu x'..and here the pod uses all the x cpus.

I tried the same test using a 'raw' docker containers, that is running my environment without kubernetes and only using docker containers. In this case the containers use all the available CPUs.

Are there any default kubernetes limitations or behavior limiting something? how can i modify them?
Thanks!

Comment: The behavior sounds like you might be limited by your messaging layer or something else, like a shared database.  Have you looked across the cluster to see if there's any part under particular load, or tried to profile one instance of your pod to see where it's spending time?

Comment: Please add the manifest of the workload

Comment: @DavidMaze the MOM does not seem to be suffering, in fact testing the same system without kubernetes and only with docker, the P1 Pod uses more CPU. Maybe is Flannel limiting the bandwidth in some way?

Comment: @Thomas what do you mean for 'workload'?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

1. The fact that you were able to stress the CPU fully with `stress --cpu x` when logging into your pod's container is evidence that k8s is functioning correctly when pod requests resources on the worker node. So, resource requests and limits are functional.
2. You should consider if your network traffic that one `P1` pod is handling is actually enough to generate a high CPU utilisation. Typically, you need to generate a VERY HIGH amount of network traffic to get a service to utilize a lot of CPU since such a workload is `network latency centric` and not `compute power centric`.
3. You describe that when increasing your P1 pods, your loads/pod decreases that is because your `Service` object is doing a great job. `Service` objects are responsible for load balancing incoming traffic equally to all the pods that are serving the traffic. The fact that CPU load reduces is evidence that since there are more pods to serve the incoming traffic, the load is naturally distributed across them by the `Service` abstraction.
4. When you define a very large number for your request quota two things can happen:

a. If there is no `admission control` in your cluster (an application that processes all the incoming API requests and performs actions on it, like validation/compliance/security checks), your pod will be stuck in `Pending` state, since there will be no `Node` big enough for the scheduler to be able to fit your pod.

b. If there is an `admission-controller` setup, it will try to enforce a maximum allowable quota by overriding the value of quota in your manifest before it is sent to the API server for processing. So, even if you specify 10 in your vCPU request, if the `admission-controller` has a rule which doesn't allow more than 2 vCPUs in quota, it will be changed to `2` by the controller. You can verify this isn't the case by printing your `Pod` and looking at the quota fields if they are the same as the ones you specified when applying you might not have an `admission-controller` in your cluster.

> I would suggest a better way to approach the problem would be to test your Pod with a reasonable/realistic maximum value of traffic that you expect on 1 node and then record the CPU usage and memory usage. You can then instead of attempting to get the Pod to use more CPU, you can resize your node into a smaller sized node, this way, your pod will have less CPU available and hence better utilisation :)

This is a very common design pattern (especially for scenario like yours where you have 1pod/worker node). This allows to have light-weight easy scale-out architectures which can perform really well along with autoscaling of nodes.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! I will use your tips! But, it is required to me to use all the available CPUs. The fact is that the Service exposes outside the cluster the MOM (which for the time being has only 1 instance) and not directly P1. So there is a strange behavior, because whithout kubernetes the P1 uses all the CPUs, while under k8s and under a certain traffic it uses less CPUs. In fact the non-k8s environment and the k8s one share the same performance when the traffic (aka clients msg send/receive) is not too heavy. I used Flannel in my k8s cluster: could it be the problem?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "service exposes an instance and not P1"? Service objects in k8s expose a set of pods, not instances. Even for nodePort service types, the node instance is just a 'router' of sorts, the service is still provided by the pods.

Comment: Also, why is it necessary to "use all the CPU"? You can simply resize your instances so you will run 2 instances half the size at 100%, instead of 1 instance at 50%. You will still be using 100% CPU resources, just distributed across 2 instances. I don't see why you want to use 100% and want to match a non-k8s environment. Are you seeing performance degradation when moving to k8s?

Comment: yes, sorry, I thought "pod" and I wrote "instance" xD. And yes, in k8s i saw performance degradation when the clients' sending message rate is too high. Instead, when their publishing rate is not heavy, the k8s and the non-k8s environment has more or less the same performance.

Comment: The issue can be with the rest of the request path. application pods are the "end" of the request path. There are many other components that are there in your infrastructure that will need tuning. My suggestion was, since that might be complicated to do, it is instead, better to simply shrink the size of the instance where your pods run, (so your CPU utilization improves) and then scale out these smaller instances with an autoscaler of some kind. SInce your objective is to improve CPU utilization, not to "make pods use more CPU".

Comment: thank you very much! Sorry for my silence! I used your tips, finding some problems, and I will reuse them in future. One of the problems I found was my virtualizer, because it has limited CPU power and so once some pods started using a lot of CPU, the others could not use it as desired. Anyway, thank you very much again, see you soon!